# What brand/model was Sirius Black's Muggle motorbike?

Tags: harry-potter

Apparently, Sirius Black's enchanted motorbike was exceptionally large:

> A low rumbling sound had broken the silence around them. It grew steadily louder as they looked up and down the street for some sign of a headlight; it swelled to a roar as they both looked up at the sky – **and a huge motorbike fell out of the air and landed on the road in front of them**.
>   <sub>*Philosopher's Stone* - page 16 - Bloomsbury - chapter one, *The Boy Who Lived*</sub>

Sirius Black isn't described as a particularly large or burly guy, but I'm sure *any* Muggle motorbike might have been hard for Sirius to come by, based on his staunchly anti-Muggle-leaning parents. What kind of Muggle motorbike would be considered "huge", especially huge enough to hold Hagrid in *Philosopher's Stone* and *Deathly Hallows*? It would also have to be able to accommodate a sidecar, as we know from *Deathly Hallows* in the chapter *The Seven Potters*.

**What brand/model was Sirius Black's Muggle motorbike?**

**<sub>I'm not referring to the *Harry Potter* movies; I'd like to know about the books, i.e. canon.</sub>**

Comment: I'd totally answer this, but I'm afraid I might spoil something if you haven't read *all* the books. ; )

Comment: @MeatTrademark - I actually have read all the books! You can always use the spoiler tag if you'd like. I'd be interested in what you have to say. :)

Comment: *It was a joke.* You're well-known to probably be the foremost expert on the subject here. :P

Comment: @MeatTrademark - I got the joke even if she didn't...

Comment: For the record, the films are canon.

Comment: @Richard -- They are not canon to me. Or, rather, they are one of the lowest levels of canon available. Don't get me wrong -- I adore the movies! I think they're a lovely visual representation of what JKR's universe could look like. I watch them very frequently. The discrepancies between the books and the movies, though, are too many and too vast for me to consider them canon proper. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @Richard -- Oh, for the love of Pete ... I got the joke and my response was completely tongue-in-cheek, if not a bit dry. Tone doesn't always translate well online, eh? ;)

Comment: It was a [_Flying Merkel_](http://www.theflyingmerkel.com/site/) - obviously!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sirius_Black%27s_motorbike);

> - The motorcycle used in the film adaptation of Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone was a white 1959 Triumph 650 T 120 Bonneville.
>
> [image]

**Early Concept Art**
[image]

> - The 1959 Triumph 650 T 120 Bonneville is also used to represent the motorcycle in the film adaptations of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows but this time it has a blue side car attached.
> - The Triumph Bonneville was not used in the motorcycle escape scene in Deathly Hallows part one. It was a light blue Royal Enfield.

**The brand isn't mentioned in the book series itself**, but this image from one of the [licensed jigsaws](http://www.galleon.ph/product/detail/2707973/harry-potter-hagrid-on-motorcyle-chopper-550-piece-jigsaw-puzzle) (which pre-dates the film by about three years) appears to be some kind of [chopper](http://motorcycley.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/motorcycle-chopper-5.jpg)

[image]

Comment: The Triumph Bonneville enjoys legendary status amongst motorcyclists too young (or just too fortunate) to have ever ridden one :-)

Comment: that looks like the front of a jigsaw puzzle box, not a book cover?

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - I think you may be right.

Comment: Not a big fan of the HP Wikia. Their information is so often incorrect. I should have clarified that I wasn't referring to the movies, so will edit that.

Comment: @Slytherincess - Not trusting the HP wikia, I went and had a look at each brand of motorbike!

Comment: Triumph press page confirming the Bonneville: http://www.triumphmotorcycles.com/triumph-world/press Press release that mentions the Royal Enfield: http://www.livemint.com/Companies/Dt2jA34Gsdum7hR5OP6HzN/Royal-Enfieldmaker-Eicher-Motors-in-overseas-sales-push.html

Comment: @alexwlchan - Nice find. I used a far less intelligent approach and just looked at a picture of the make/model ;-)